# How to resize system partition in Win 10 on a virtual machine when unallocated space is not next to the partition?

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning

I've read some guides about resizing the system partition. But they all seem to require the unallocated space to come directly after the partition I want to resize. But I have this:

[image]

I might add that I'm running it in a VM with qemu and virt-manager on Fedora. I managed to resize the harddrive with qemu, but the partition gave me problems.

I tried using EaseUS Partition Master, but the trial version only allowed a preview of the result.

Comment: @JW0914 This is one of the reasons to not install Windows ;)

Comment: That makes no rational sense

Comment: @JW0914 Was not meant to. It was just a rant. :)

Comment: @JW0914 in this example, does WinRE means 509MB partition and Boot means 500 MB partition?

Comment: @Grace WinRE is the 509MB partition [**Win**dows **Re**covery], however my previous comment was wrong, as WinRE should be after the OS partition, not before it - Microsoft made this the default in v2004, as the `Winre.wim` increases in size with version updates, so when placed in front of the OS partition, if the `Winre.wim` outgrew it, the bi-annual update would create a second WinRE partition due to this, resulting with two WinRE partitions and only the latter active.

Answer (score 4):

Use
[GParted Live](https://gparted.org/livecd.php)
to boot the VM.

Move the 509 MB partition to the end of the disk, so the unallocated
space will follow `C:`.

Now you will be able to resize `C:` to include this space.

Note that this is best done from the Windows Disk Management,
rather than from a Linux utility.

Comment: Be ABSOLUTELY sure the Windows installation in the VM was shutdown properly (Fast boot option disabled and then do a shutdown in Windows) or you will end up with a corrupted Windows installation. The extend of the C: drive to include the extra space can safely be done from GParted. (Extending a NTFS disk in GParted is no more dangerous than doing it in Windows itself.).

Comment: @Tonny The easier way is to hold shift and then select reboot in start menu. Then Windows makes sure to fully shut down and it additionally allows you to directly select the boot drive to boot from.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: It would make more sense to move WinRE in front of the OS partition, albeit moving a 509MB partition will take less time than a 39GB partition.

Comment: @Tonny You misunderstand me. You hold the shift key when clicking on "Shutdown" in Windows 10, not when the PC boots. Just try it out. Insert a bootable USB stick and click reboot in Windows start menu while holding shift key. Then Windows shows a special menu before finally going down.

Comment: @Robert You are right of course. My bad. I had almost no sleep last night and a very very long day. Despite several liters of coffee it seems my brain is no longer firing on all cylinders. Time to sign off.

Comment: @JW0914 Maybe, but isn't it much riskier to move the OS partition?

Comment: @klutt Not really - I'd capture a WIM prior to doing so, but this is one of the reasons it's recommended to place WinRE as the first partition and not the last _(partition order: WinRE, Boot, OS)_, as not doing so means enlarging the OS partition will be an inconvenience and it becomes problematic with SSDs since they should be over-provisioned [OP], with the OP space generally coming by unallocating space from the last partition _(SSDs should have 10% of the drive size set aside for over-provisioning to ensure the lifespan of the SSD isn't affected)_