# How to resize system partition in Win 10 on a physical machine when unallocated space is not next to the partition?

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, gparted

I asked a [very similar question earlier](https://superuser.com/q/1659687/707055)

Previous question:

> I've read some guides about resizing the system partition. But they all seem to require the unallocated space to come directly after the partition I want to resize. But I have this:
>
> [image]

The only difference between this and the previous question is that this time I'm NOT running Windows in a virtual machine. When I was using a virtual machine, harrymc's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1659692/707055) worked like a charm.

But this time it didn't. I created a bootable usb stick with GParted, booted it up, moved the partition to the end and rebooted. But when I entered Windows, there where no changes. I tried it again while not only moving the recovery partition, but also resizing the C: partition directly in GParted. Again, no changes where visible when I booted back into Windows.

I'm open to the idea to use other tools than GParted. Just need to get the job done.

Comment: You mean that you used GParted to move the 509 MB partition to the end of the disk, but it didn't move?

Comment: @harrymc Exactly. From what I saw, I got no indication from GParted that it did not work.

Comment: Seems very strange. Try [Paragon Partition Manager Community Edition](https://www.paragon-software.com/free/pm-express/#), which has a bootable version (may not be required).

Comment: @harrymc I'll try once more to see if there where any error messages I missed.

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference whether you do this on a VM or real hardware. Are you sure you actually commited the changes made in GParted? Did you check the GParted logs after the attempted partition move?

Comment: @Tonny Nope, I did not. How do I do that? Also, one thing that's VERY strange is that when I reboot into GParted, it looks like the changes are actually performed. But not in Windows...

Comment: And the fact that GParted and Disk manager shows different makes me a bit nervous about the systems current state.

Comment: Please include current screenshots from _Disk Management_ and _GParted_

Comment: Something extremely strange happened. I installed Paragon as harrymc suggested. When I started it, the computer crashed and Windows did some auto repair. And after that, the changes I made in GParted could be seen in Disk Manager. Spooky. But the system seem to be fine now.

Answer (score 3):

From the extra information in your last comment I suspect your disk has both a GPT and a (backup) MBR partition table.
This is rare, but not unheard off, especially on a system that has run in UEFI with CSM enabled at some point in its life.
Normally these partition tables contain the same basic information, but somehow they got out of sync.
Windows must have used the GPT and GParted updated the MBR (or vice versa).

The crash caused Windows to verify the boot process and sync both partition tables up again.
Just to be safe have Windows do a full disk check on the C: drive. Windows may not realize by itself that might be needed.

Comment: C: check shouldn't be necessary, as that partition wasn't moved.

Comment: @gronostaj It wasn't moved but it's size was altered (enlarged) in a weird way with a crash in between. Better safe than sorry.